# evento onclick do javascript com três funções

Tags: javascript

Pq só está funcionando a última função do método addEventListener do meu script. Estou desenvolvendo filtros em uma DataTable que quando clico no botão de buscar ele filtra na tabela as informações. As funções de filtro estão funcionando, porém só funciona individual.

HTML:

```
<label for="proto">Protocolo</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="proto" id="proto" 
 placeholder="Pesquisar...">

<label for="nome">Nome</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome"  
placeholder="Pesquisar...">

<label for="doc">Documento</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="doc" id="doc" 
placeholder="Pesquisar...">

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="btnBuscar">Buscar</button>
```

Script:

```
function proto() {
    var proto, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    proto = document.getElementById("proto");
    filter = proto.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("table");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }    
    } 
}

function nome() {
    var nome, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    nome = document.getElementById("nome");
    filter = nome.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("table");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }    
    }       
}

function doc() {
    var doc, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    doc = document.getElementById("doc");
    filter = doc.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("table");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }    
    }   
}

document.getElementById("btnBuscar").addEventListener("click", function(){
    proto();
    doc();
    nome();
});
```

Comment: Leandro a chamada para as 3 funções está correta, verfique no console do seu navegador  se não é exibido nenhum erro, tente adicionar o html a sua pergunta para podermos testar as funções :)

Comment: @CaiqueRomero Inseri o Html, no console não mostra erro algum.

Comment: explique exatamente seu erro e o que está acontecendo, adicione a pergunta, se possível anexe uma imagem com o que está acontecendo e o que deveria acontecer por favor

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Então não tenho como te informar o erro pois não da erro no console, simplesmente o botão não faz a filtragem na tabela com o clique no botão.

Comment: Ocorre algum erro no console?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Não ocorreu não, continua a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade, os 3 estão funcionando, como o console sem erros mostra.

O que acontece é que, independente do que você fez antes, a última chamada vai sobrescrever ou apagar o valor de `tr[i].style.display`.

O que pode fazer, mantendo o javascript puro nas funções, é criar uma função para "resetar" tudo, limpando os displays e, por consequência, mostrar tudo, e em seguida chamar as funções, que só colocam o `display: none`, sem mudar o conteúdo quando o filtro passar.

```
    function resetFilters() {
        table = document.getElementById("table");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        }
    }

    function filterByText(filter, tdColumn) {
        table = document.getElementById("table");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[tdColumn];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }    
        } 
    }

    function proto() {
        var proto, filter;
        proto = document.getElementById("proto");
        filter = proto.value.toUpperCase();
        filterByText(filter, 0);
    }

    function nome() {
        var nome, filter;
        nome = document.getElementById("nome");
        filter = nome.value.toUpperCase();
        filterByText(filter, 3);
    }

    function doc() {
        var doc, filter;
        doc = document.getElementById("doc");
        filter = doc.value.toUpperCase();
        filterByText(filter, 4);
    }

    document.getElementById("btnBuscar").addEventListener("click", function(){
        resetFilters()
        proto();
        doc();
        nome();
    });
```

Comment: o seu funcionou aí? Aqui comigo aconteceu que apenas a última função chamada, ou seja, nome() aplicou o filtro as outras não.

Comment: não cheguei a testar, não tenho a tabela pronta, mas editei pois encontrei erros na minha modificação, veja se vai agora

Comment: Perfeito man, funcionou certinho, muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi muito bem, voce quer atribuir um evento de click e chamar estas 3 funções?

Se sim

```
$(botao).click(function () {
  proto();
  nome();
  doc();
});
```

Comment: Assim já testei com jQuery e javascript e não funciona.

Comment: Eu realmente não entendi direito o que você quer, e qual seu erro

Comment: Quero que quando vou no input de filtro de protocolos e aperto o botão a tabela mostra o resultado do filtro na tabela, ok, isto já funciona se for só com a função proto(), porém se eu for no input de nome e digitar um nome, na tabela não acontece nada, a função nome(), não executa.

Comment: Então o que passei nao resolve seu problema, perdão.

Comment: que isso cara, não precisa pedir perdão não, tentou ajudar, isto já é muito bacana.

Answer (score -1):

Você também pode fazer direto pelo `HTML`

```
<button onclick="proto();doc();nome()" ...
```

Comment: Já testei assim direto no html, não funciona.

Comment: Esse código funciona como um filtro que percorre a tabela e seta `display: none` nas linhas que que não são relacionadas ao filtro, certo? não tenho certeza mas acredito que os 3 estão funcionando porém estão sendo sobrescritos, no caso `doc()` sobre escreve `proto()` e `nome()` sobre escreve `doc()`,

Comment: Exatamente isto que ocorre na tabela, mas, pq uma função sobrescreve a outra, se essa é a maneira correta de se invocar funções em um mesmo evento?

Comment: Bom se eu estiver certo o que ocorre é que quando tu chama o primeiro evento ele seta `display: none` em certa linha por causa desse filtro e quando tu chama a segunda ele seta em branco o `display` dessa mesma linha, acredito que é isso que está ocorrendo

Comment: Você precisa usar mais de um filtro? Exemplo nome Gui e proto 123 apenas um único filtro por vez é suficiente?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostalmim Não só um filtro apenas. Editei a pergunta e introduzi uma imagem para ser mais claro.

Comment: Bom nao tenho como elaborar um codigo agr tenho  que sair, mas tenho uma ideia: faz uma unica funcao com 3 ifs que verifica se o input nao esta vazio se nao eativer executa o filtro reapectivo senai vai pro proximo no ultimo else voce pode colocar um alerta de que todos os campos estao vazios, dai é so chamar essa unica funcao no botao